# JBL's Quantum does detect plugged JBL headset

Tags: wine, headset

I recently bought a JBL headset called [JBL Quantum 400](https://www.jbl.com.br/headset-gamer/QUANTUM400.html) that has support software called Quantum Software. This software is only available for Windows, so I installed it using Wine (wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)) and it went well. My Ubuntu version is 20.04.1 LTS.

The thing is, Quantum Software does not detect my headset, regardless of whether I plug it with the jack or USB. I can't do any tweaks or updates on my headphone's firmware, nor can I set it to be used to its full potential.

Another thing that's going on that might have something to do with this issue is that Ubuntu does not detect the built in mic of the headset when it's plugged via USB. That is, when I go to Settings > Sound, the built in mic is not listed.

Thanks in advance for your time guys.

Have a nice day

Comment: Wine is probably not going to unlock the software-only features of your hardware if the software is not for Linux. If you bought this hardware with the intent to use it on Linux, and you need these software features, I suggest you return it within the return window and obtain hardware that either doesn't require software, or from a manufacturer who writes their software to work on Linux/Ubuntu.  Wine is a compatibility layer.  It is not a panacea.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with JBL Quantum 800.
Problem was solved when i install [Sound Switcher Indicator](https://snapcraft.io/indicator-sound-switcher).
I've just switch input/output when it's needed.

Installiation:

```bsh
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yktooo/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-switcher
```

Comment: didn't work for me - nothing to switch to since there is just no jbl mic found on ubuntu

Comment: good answer, worked for me on ubuntu 18